# Check if $\bigcup \mathcal A \cup \bigcup \mathcal B = \bigcup (\mathcal{A \cup B})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Check if $\bigcup \mathcal A \cup \bigcup \mathcal B = \bigcup (\mathcal{A \cup B})$

I am new to set theory and the only thing I know about the sum of  a family of sets is its definition, and so I tried to evaluate the lefthand side of this:
$$x \in \bigcup \mathcal A \cup \bigcup \mathcal B \iff (\exists A\in\mathcal A )(x \in A) \lor (\exists B \in \mathcal B)(x \in B) $$
Right now I am totally stuck and don't have the faintest idea how to continue - the quantifiers make it unable to conduct further logical evaluations. I would be glad if you could explain this to me in simple terms.

Comment: If there is either $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in A$ or $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$, then must there be $C \in \mathcal{A}\cup \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in C$? (You can consider the two cases separately.) How about the converse?

Comment: Intuitively, the first part of what you wrote appears to be true but I don't have an idea how to write it formally, based on logical evaluations.

Comment: If $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are sets of sets, then we just have that $\bigcup\mathcal A = \mathcal A$. Do you mean $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal A} A$?

Comment: @Wolfups $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ is another notation for $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions.

Comment: @Aemillius I'm not sure what you mean "based on logical evaluations," but the proof would go something like this: If $x \in \bigcup\mathcal{A}$, then either there exists $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in A$, or there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. In the first case, let $C=A$ and note $x \in C \in \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$. In the second case, let $C=B$ and note $x \in B \in \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$. So in any case, there exists $C \in \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in C$. You would still have to show the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \bigcup\mathcal{A}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{B}$
$$\Rightarrow ( x\in A \text{ for some } A\in \mathcal{A})\vee( x\in B \text{ for some } B\in \mathcal{B}) $$
By definition we have: $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B} = \{ x \cup y\space |\space x\in\mathcal{A} \wedge y\in\mathcal{B}\}$. Therefore $(A\cup B) \in \mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$.
$$\Rightarrow (x\in A) \vee (x\in B) \text{ for } (A\cup B)\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x\in A\cup B) \text{ for } (A\cup B)\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in \bigcup(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$$
Thus $\bigcup\mathcal{A}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{B}\subset\bigcup(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$.

Now take $x\in\bigcup(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$

$$x\in C \text{ for some } C\in(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$$

Again, by definition: if $C\in(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$, then there exists $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $C=A\cup B$.
$$\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B \text{ for } A\in\mathcal{A} \text{ and } B\in\mathcal{B}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x\in A \text{ for } A\in\mathcal{A}) \vee (x\in B \text{ for } B\in\mathcal{B})$$
$$\Rightarrow (x\in\bigcup\mathcal{A}) \vee (x\in\bigcup\mathcal{B})$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in \bigcup\mathcal{A}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{B}$$
Therefore  $\bigcup(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})\subset\bigcup\mathcal{A}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{B}$.

Finally we have that $\bigcup\mathcal{A}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{B}=\bigcup(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})$